# Why can't I use CMakeLists.txt inside a subfolder on VS Code, but I can when I add another CMakeLists.txt on the root folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-extensions

When I put only a CMakeLists.txt inside a subfolder, it does not work. But, when I add another CMakeLists.txt on the root folder with `add_subdirectory` command, it works. Why does it need a CMakeLists.txt on the root folder? Can I have only one CMakeLists.txt inside a subfolder which works?

The system that I used:

- OS: Windows 10
- VS Code Version: VS Code 1.83.1
- CMake version: 3.27.6
- CMake Tools (vs code extension): 1.15.31

This is the structure of my C++ project

```
my_project/
-- my_project/
---- CMakeLists.txt
---- src/
------ main.cpp
```

This is my main.cpp

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Bismillah hello world\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(my_project)

add_executable(my_project_main src/main.cpp)
```

When I pressed Ctrl + Shift + P and then choose CMake: Configure, it asked me for the location of the CMakeLists.txt. I chose the file above but after that it showed

> "Configure failed. Would you like to attempt to configure with the CMake Debugger?"

I press the button "Debug" but it still showed me the same message.

However, when I make another CMakeLists.txt on the root folder like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(root_of_my_project)

add_subdirectory(my_project)
```

It worked. Why is this?

Comment: historically related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/533, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/2066

Comment: if you're getting failing configuration, I'd be more suspicious of that first. does configuration fail if you run it "manually" via commandline? Please show us what command VS Code used to run configuration, and show us the full output of the configuration command.

Comment: I followed your second link and I attempted to reopen the VS Code. It works! Now my project uses only the CMakeLists.txt on the subfolder. Thanks! I think you should make an answer for this and I will accept that answer @starball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a historically related-sounding issue ticket: ["Locating" a CMakeLists.txt file does not fully activate cmake-tools
#2066](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/2066). It's purportedly fixed, but apparently (according to the asker) the workaround stated in the question post solves the problem stated in the question post here: Close and reopen the workspace / close and reopen VS Code.